# How to fix app not installing compiled apk on my mobile device, using generating signed APK of react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I currently new developing android react-native, I have problem regarding deploying my application on other mobile device, I read the documentation of react native How to generate signed APK, i did the instruction of there document

[React Native signed-apk-android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android)

I already done configuring  those requirements based on there document. I will show you the step that I did.

**First: Install this in the cmd**

```
keytool -genkeypair -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

**Second: Setting up gradle variables**

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore

MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias

MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=123456

MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=123456
```

**Third: Adding signing config to your app's gradle config**

```
    ...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
...
```

**Lastly: Generating the release APK
Simply run the following in a terminal:**

```
$ cd android
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

> Before I do the installation, I gonna make sure that the package
>   clearly uninstalled on my mobile device.

**Release APK:**
[image: APK file]

**Error:**

[image: Error Captured]

Answer (score 0):

you need to click on the apk (probably with developer mode active press a few times on the build number in the settings menu)

Comment: what do you mean for this jonathan,? can you show to me the example thanks

Comment: here is a small guide on where to find the develoepr options 
https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-get-developer-options-on-android/

Comment: oh you need to transfer the apk to your phone
then jsut navigate to the apk on your phone and click on it